# How to check whether the substring is present in a string in Nunjucks Template

Tags: nunjucks

If we have a string like "This is High Price" how can I check whether "high"  is present in that string or not in Nunjucks Template

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/mozilla/nunjucks/issues/676#issuecomment-184750064), discovered `in` works like so: `"high" in "This is High Price"`

Note: This is case-sensitive search.

Comment: See this thread for folks who need to do a [case *insensitive* search](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59253725/1366033)