# How to do case insensitive string comparison in Nunjucks

Tags: javascript, case-insensitive, nunjucks

I'm trying to do a case insensitive match inside of an `{% if %}` statement

The following two approaches do *not* work:

```js
{% set role = 'APP' %}

{% if 'app' == role %}  1 {% endif %}
{% if 'app' in role  %} 2 {% endif %}
```

Nunucks only has a little documentation on their [comparison operators](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#comparisons), but don't refer to specific types.

Nunjucks is a port of Jinja2 and there is a similar question on [how to lowercase a string in Jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23195321/1366033)

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the [built in filters](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#builtin-filters) like [`lower`](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#lower) to transform the string or nunjucks allows you to execute a limited set of JavaScript inside of expressions so calling `toLowerCase()` will also work.

Any of the following 3 approaches will work:

1 `{% if 'app' == role.toLowerCase() %} 1 {% endif %}`
2 `{% if 'app' == role | lower %} 2 {% endif %}`
3 `{% set role_lower = 'App' | lower %} {% if 'app' == role_lower %} 3 {% endif %}`